# How to horizontally align floated contents

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want my copyright floated to the left and a back to top button floated to the right, but I can't align/ center them both horizontally. I tried doing display:inline-block

```css
.wrap {
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3%;
  position: relative;
}
footer {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 20vh;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.backtotop {
  float: right;
}
.copyright {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="wrap">
    <a class="backtotop" href="#header">
      BACK TO TOP <span class="arrow">↑</span>
    </a>
    <p class="copyright">ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Remove default `margin` of `p`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the flx properties into the the `.wrap` element. Then you can remove the floats completely.

```css
.wrap {
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
footer {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding:0 3em
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="wrap">
    <a class="backtotop" href="#header">BACK TO TOP <span class="arrow">↑</span></a>
    <p class="copyright">ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a margin on your `<p>` but not on your `<a>`, if you remove it from both, or add it to both, you will achieve what you wish to accomplish.

(It's worth noting that while you didn't add the margin yourself, the browser user agent adds it in by default, unless you specify otherwise. Different browsers set different default CSS rules. Try including a reset.css or a normalise.css )